# How to prevent a callback from being interrupted by a figure's close function?

Tags: matlab

Was wondering how the question in the title can be achieved. I have some callbacks that run from button presses. These callbacks, if interrupted by the figure close, will cause errors because the function seems to run, then gets interrupted by the close function which closes the figure, and then the callback seems to resume after the figure is closed.

If I set the button's `'Interruptible'` property to `'on'`, it prevents other callbacks from interrupting it, but does not seem to work for the figure's close function. Another idea I had was to specify the `'closefunction'` in the figuring's `'CloseRequestFcn'` callback and then call `drawnow` to flush the eventqueue before deleting the figure but this did not work.

The last resort for me is to simply set the figure's `'CloseRequestFcn'` to `''` when running callbacks but this seems tedious. Is there a standard solution to accomplish this?

EDIT:

From matlab's documentation:

> Note   If the interrupting callback is a DeleteFcn or CreateFcn
>   callback or a figure's CloseRequest or ResizeFcn callback, it
>   interrupts an executing callback regardless of the value of that
>   object's Interruptible property. The interrupting callback starts
>   execution at the next drawnow, figure, getframe, pause, or waitfor
>   statement. A figure's WindowButtonDownFcn callback routine, or an
>   object's ButtonDownFcn or Callback routine are processed according to
>   the rules described above.

So it appears to be the case that the `interruptible` property doesn't effect the close function.

EDIT 2:

Ok, so I think I found a problem. It's really bizarre. I actually discovered from the matlab documentation that callbacks are only interruptible if they have the `interruptible` property set to `on` AND :

`If there is a drawnow, figure, getframe, waitfor, or pause command in the running callback, then MATLAB executes the interrupting callbacks which are already in the queue and returns to finish execution of the current callback.`

I don't use any of these functions explicitly, so it turns out most of my callbacks aren't interruptible by the `closereqfcn`. BUT, it turns out some are, and the reasons why seem very strange. If have a callback with:

`large computation -> imshow -> imshow

`large computation -> set -> set -> set -> set`

where the `set` command is setting the axes `visible` property to `off`, then no interruption seems to occur if I exit during the callback

Now, if I have:

`large computation -> imshow -> set -> imshow -> set`

matlab issues an error if I exit during the callback on the second `set` command. Also, if I have:

`large computation -> imshow -> imshow -> set`

matlab issues an error if I exit during the callback on the first `set` command.

`large computation -> imshow -> imshow -> imshow`

also issues an error on the third `imshow` if I cancel during the callback.

For some reason it seems that two successive calls to `imshow` makes my callback interruptible. Is it possible matlab implicitly calls `drawnow` or does something weird if you use multiple `imshow`s? BTW, my matlab version is R2009a.

Comment: One workaround could be starting a timer in `CloseRequestFcn` and in the timer callback try to close the figure if it is not interrupting any important callback by checking a **flag** (`close_allowed`) which you set to false when the figure should not be closed (such as during the important progresses).

Comment: It seems to me the actual problem causing errors is that the data used in your callback gets deleted with the figure. It might be an idea to create a copy of the data you need outside the figure (a good practice anyway). Maybe with `copyfig` to a hidden window, or just manually store all you need at beginning of your callback . Just be sure to clean it up after you are done.

Comment: @bdecaf Its not just that. Sometimes i have to update the visible figure axes. If this callback gets interrupted by the figure closing then it tries to update an axes handle that doesn't exist. It seems very strange matlab would do this. This appears to make any callback suseptible to being interrupted by the figure closing. How does one make updating an axes safe from this behavior?

Comment: Thinking about just placing a `try-catch` statement around each callback... This seems like the most compact solution sadly...

Comment: If you have lengthy calculations it might make sense to implement some logic so that you can cancel them. This is a good practice so functions whose output is no longer needed won't waste your resources.  But I agree with you that this feature should be provided by matlab.

Answer (score 2):

I never really trusted that `Interruptible` flag (or comparable mechanisms)...I immediately admit I have never used it a lot, but that was because when I was experimenting with it for the first time, I noticed that `'Interruptible'`, `'off'` (and friends) seemed to have more exceptions to the rule than vindications of it -- headache material alert!

So, I got in the habit of tackling this sort of problem simply by using flags, and wrapping all callbacks that must *really* be uninterruptible in a locking/releasing function.

Something like this:

```
% Define a button
uicontrol(...
    'style', 'pushbutton',...
    'interruptible', 'off',... % Nice, but doesn't catch DeleteFcn, CreateFcn, ...
                               % CloseRequestFcn or ResizeFcn
    % ...
    % further definition of button 
    % ...

    % Put callback in a wrapper:
    'callback', @(src,evt) uninterruptibleCallback(@buttonCallback, src,evt)...
);
```

where `uninterruptibleCallback()` looks something like this:

```
function varargout = uninterruptibleCallback(callback, varargin)

    % only execute callback when 'idle'
    % (you can omit this if you don't want such strict ordering of callbacks)
    while ~strcmp( get(mainFigure, 'userData'), 'idle' )
        pause(0.01);
        % ...or some other action you desire
    end

    % LOCK
    set(mainFigure, 'userData', 'busy');

    try
        % call the "real" callback
        [varargout{:}] = callback(varargin{:});

        % UNLOCK
        set(mainFigure, 'userData', 'idle');

    catch ME
        % UNLOCK
        set(mainFigure, 'userData', 'idle');

        throw(ME);
    end

end
```

Which allows you to use this `closeReqFcn()` for your figure:

```
function closeReqFcn(~,~)

    % only when the currently running locked callback (if any) has finished
    while ~strcmp( get(mainFigure, 'userData'), 'idle' )
        pause(0.01);
        % ...or some other action you desire
    end

    % ... 
    % further clean-up tasks
    % ... 

    % deletion
    delete(mainFigure);

end
```

Theoretically, when you put *all* callbacks in this sort of schema, it is basically equal to managing your own event queue.

This of course has a few advantages, but many, many drawbacks -- you might want to think this through for a bit. This whole mechanism might be unacceptably slow for your use case, or you might need to define a few more locking functions with far more specific behavior.

In any case, I suspect it's a good place to start off from.

Comment: Doesn't the close request function run to completion before returning to the interrupted callback? In that case, it seems `'userData'` will always remain not `idle`.

Comment: @jucestain: you mean that the close request function should also lock the GUI?

Comment: I was interpreting the `while` loop in your `closeReqFcn` as a way to pause the execution until the interrupted callback is finished running. My understanding is that the closeReqFcn completes before returning back to the callback that was interrupted, and will thus be in a deadlock because it's waiting for interrupted callback to complete. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Rody Oldenhuis's solution is to start a timer inside the `CloseRequestFcn` to close the figure when no uninterruptible code is in progress (which could be indicated by a flag; `Closing_Allowed`).

```
function mainFig_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    Time = 3; % Wait time before force killing (in sec)
    Kill.tmr = timer('executionMode', 'fixedRate',...
        'Period', 1/10,...
        'TimerFcn', {@KillingTimer_Callback, handles});
    Kill.counts = ceil(Time/Kill.tmr.Period);

    setappdata(handles.mainFig,'Kill',Kill);

    start(Kill.tmr);

function KillingTimer_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    Kill = getappdata(handles.mainFig,'Kill');
    Kill.counts = Kill.counts - 1; % Count down
    setappdata(handles.mainFig,'Kill',Kill);

    if Kill.counts == 0 || getappdata(handles.mainFig, 'Closing_Allowed')
        stop(Kill.tmr);
        delete(handles.mainFig);
    end
```

`if Kill.counts == 0` means **time out**, and closes the figure even if an uninterruptible task is in progress, which then would result in the same errors you get sometimes now, but if you know the maximum amount of time you need to finish the uninterruptible jobs, then you can set the `Time` above properly.

Finally wrap the uninterruptible code by setting the `Closing_Allowed` flag.

```
function pushbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    setappdata(handles.mainFig, 'Closing_Allowed', 0); % Closing is not allowed
    pause(2);
    setappdata(handles.mainFig, 'Closing_Allowed', 1); % Closing is allowed
```